# 404 not found errors when using Modx CMS in a subfolder

Tags: seo, htaccess, apache, modx

I have installed Modx CMS on my hosting provider, but instead of installing it on my root directory where it usually goes, I put it in a folder on the root directory called makeabio.

directory loads fine but when I click on a link in my page it would take me to the index.php file located outside the folder in the main directory. I believe it has something to do with the .htaccess file. I provided it below.

```
# MODX supports Friendly URLs via this .htaccess file. You must serve web
# pages via Apache with mod_rewrite to use this functionality, and you must
# change the file name from ht.access to .htaccess.
#
# Make sure RewriteBase points to the directory where you installed MODX.
# E.g., "/modx" if your installation is in a "modx" subdirectory.
#
# You may choose to make your URLs non-case-sensitive by adding a NC directive
# to your rule: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!makeabio/)(.+)$ /index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^makeabio/(.+)$ /makeabio/index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L] 

# Rewrite www.domain.com -> domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example-domain-please-change\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://example-domain-please-change.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#
# or for the opposite domain.com -> www.domain.com use the following
# DO NOT USE BOTH
#
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example-domain-please-change\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example-domain-please-change.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Rewrite secure requests properly to prevent SSL cert warnings, e.g. prevent 
# https://www.domain.com when your cert only allows https://secure.domain.com
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
#RewriteRule (.*) https://example-domain-please-change.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA] 

# Make sure .htc files are served with the proper MIME type, which is critical
# for XP SP2. Un-comment if your host allows htaccess MIME type overrides.

#AddType text/x-component .htc 

# If your server is not already configured as such, the following directive
# should be uncommented in order to set PHP's register_globals option to OFF.
# This closes a major security hole that is abused by most XSS (cross-site
# scripting) attacks. For more information: http://php.net/register_globals
#
# To verify that this option has been set to OFF, open the Manager and choose
# Reports -> System Info and then click the phpinfo() link. Do a Find on Page
# for "register_globals". The Local Value should be OFF. If the Master Value
# is OFF then you do not need this directive here.
#
# IF REGISTER_GLOBALS DIRECTIVE CAUSES 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERRORS :
#
# Your server does not allow PHP directives to be set via .htaccess. In that
# case you must make this change in your php.ini file instead. If you are
# using a commercial web host, contact the administrators for assistance in
# doing this. Not all servers allow local php.ini files, and they should
# include all PHP configurations (not just this one), or you will effectively
# reset everything to PHP defaults. Consult www.php.net for more detailed
# information about setting PHP directives.

#php_flag register_globals Off 

# For servers that support output compression, you should pick up a bit of
# speed by un-commenting the following lines.

#php_flag zlib.output_compression On
#php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5 

# The following directives stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers. If
# needed, un-comment the following rules. When they're in place, you may have
# to do a force-refresh in order to see changes in your designs.

#ExpiresActive On
#ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
#ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
#ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
#BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
#BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
#BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
#SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary
```

I want that when I click on a link, it goes to the makeabio directory and not to the root directory.

Comment: What URLs are the links using?

Comment: Yes, but what is the _exact_ URL? Is is relative, root-relative or absolute? (Sorry, but this is an English-only site.)

Comment: @hgersitz please use English in questions, answers and comment fields. Your comments have been deleted. Please repost or edit them ensuring that you use English.

Comment: Hello English friends, this is better! My url for the site is [link](http://www.makeabio.cf), when I click on the about link it shows a 404 error!

Comment: @w3d exactly but rather having anyone on the site having to translate it, and sometimes poorly using a online translator the person posting should make an attempt to post in English. hgersitz please see [non-english policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) I believe this rule is applied on all stacks that are English.

Comment: @hgersitz: I thought you mentioned in a previous comment that `RewriteBase /makeabio` worked? Did it not?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I am English I put in the wrong stuff, @bybe

Comment: DO you know how to fix this ?

Comment: no problem, @w3d and other community members will try and assist you. The more you describe your problem the better. Just ensure that all correspondence you add is written in English.

Comment: No it never did work still shows error, check out the page url for a better understanding!  http://cheektowagawebdesign.com/makeabio/about.html @w3d

Comment: I know English will do? I sent W3d the URL to the problem it is below, http://cheektowagawebdesign.com/makeabio/about.html @bybe

Comment: In my htaccess file in the core folder in modx the following looks like this, IndexIgnore */*
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /makeabio/
</IfModule> @bybe

Answer (score 3):

Hey guys I finally figured it out, some how the code that works to do this in Modx CMS is below! This code shows you how to install it in a folder on your server.

It tells the htaccess file to read the .html extension and loads up the page without a problem.

```
#works, so happy!!

# MODX supports Friendly URLs via this .htaccess file. You must serve web
# pages via Apache with mod_rewrite to use this functionality, and you must
# change the file name from ht.access to .htaccess.
#
# Make sure RewriteBase points to the directory where you installed MODX.
# E.g., "/modx" if your installation is in a "modx" subdirectory.
#
# You may choose to make your URLs non-case-sensitive by adding a NC directive
# to your rule: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder-name/



# Rewrite www.domain.com -> domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example-domain-please-change\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://example-domain-please-change.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#
# or for the opposite domain.com -> www.domain.com use the following
# DO NOT USE BOTH
#
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example-domain-please-change\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example-domain-please-change.com/$1 [R=301,L]



# Rewrite secure requests properly to prevent SSL cert warnings, e.g. prevent 
# https://www.domain.com when your cert only allows https://secure.domain.com
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
#RewriteRule (.*) https://example-domain-please-change.com/$1 [R=301,L]



# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]



# Make sure .htc files are served with the proper MIME type, which is critical
# for XP SP2. Un-comment if your host allows htaccess MIME type overrides.

#AddType text/x-component .htc



# If your server is not already configured as such, the following directive
# should be uncommented in order to set PHP's register_globals option to OFF.
# This closes a major security hole that is abused by most XSS (cross-site
# scripting) attacks. For more information: http://php.net/register_globals
#
# To verify that this option has been set to OFF, open the Manager and choose
# Reports -> System Info and then click the phpinfo() link. Do a Find on Page
# for "register_globals". The Local Value should be OFF. If the Master Value
# is OFF then you do not need this directive here.
#
# IF REGISTER_GLOBALS DIRECTIVE CAUSES 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERRORS :
#
# Your server does not allow PHP directives to be set via .htaccess. In that
# case you must make this change in your php.ini file instead. If you are
# using a commercial web host, contact the administrators for assistance in
# doing this. Not all servers allow local php.ini files, and they should
# include all PHP configurations (not just this one), or you will effectively
# reset everything to PHP defaults. Consult www.php.net for more detailed
# information about setting PHP directives.

#php_flag register_globals Off



# For servers that support output compression, you should pick up a bit of
# speed by un-commenting the following lines.

#php_flag zlib.output_compression On
#php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5



# The following directives stop screen flicker in IE on CSS rollovers. If
# needed, un-comment the following rules. When they're in place, you may have
# to do a force-refresh in order to see changes in your designs.

#ExpiresActive On
#ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
#ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
#ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
#BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
#BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
#BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
#SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary
```

Thank you to everyone who tried to help!
@w3d @bybe

Answer (score 2):

```
# Make sure RewriteBase points to the directory where you installed MODX.
# E.g., "/modx" if your installation is in a "modx" subdirectory.

RewriteBase /
```

As stated in the comments at the top of the file, `RewriteBase` should be set to your subdirectory:

```
RewriteBase /makeabio
```

This affects the relative path substitution later in the file (half way down):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, the directives at the top of the file seem to conflict with this? Are these part of the standard setup?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!makeabio/)(.+)$ /index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^makeabio/(.+)$ /makeabio/index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Yes, you stated that in your question, that's why I included `RewriteBase /makeabio` - I didn't just make that up. Whether this fixes your problem I don't know - you'll need to try it. However, as mentioned I'm not sure about those directives at the top of the file? I'm not sure about the file extensions, but this shouldn't really matter, presumably the `.html` are on your "friendly" URLs - the .htaccess file does not deal with this.